# htaccess FilesMatch regex with version

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Need regex help in htaccess. I need to catch css and js file with version number before extension.

Files with 0 version has no cache.

Filename example:
example.0.js
example.0.css

Files with larger than 0 version has 1 year cache.

Filename example:
example.1.js
example.9999.css

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
   Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
```

This work for all js and css, but I need different cache for files *.0.js and *.0.css

Comment: You must have meant `"\.(css|js)$"`

Comment: Yes sorry I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `FilesMatch` that ends with `.0.css` or `.0.js` with `no-cache` headers. Also change existing regex to disallow `.0.(js|css)`:

```
ExpiresActive On

<FilesMatch "(?<!\.0)\.(css|js)$">
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
   Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.0\.(css|js)$">
   ExpiresDefault A0
   Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Based on your comments below here is a Apache 2.4 solution to enable caching for only `[0-9]+.(css|js)` excluding `0.`:

```
<If "'%{THE_REQUEST}' =~ /\.[0-9]+\.(css|js)/">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
   Header set Cache-Control "public"
</If>
<If "'%{THE_REQUEST}' =~ /\.0\.(css|js)/">
   ExpiresDefault A0
   Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</If>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\d+\.(css|js)$ /$1.$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks it's work. And if I have file rewrite for files, than how can I use it?
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

Comment: A keep it, and then the second filesMatch where the 0 is included, not work. I read about it, and the FilesMatch is not for requested file, is for rewrited file, but I can't find answer how could be it work.

Comment: Yes, the number is for cache versioning only, when I increase it, the browsers take the new file, but files with numbers doesn't really exist.

Comment: No back-reference of `$1` cannot be used in `Header set`. I suggest you post a new question with examples and I will try to search if it can be done using some other directive.